# Pushing a branch for a merge request that was checked out locally via merge request ID

Tags: git, gitlab, merge-request

I am handling merge requests in Gitlab and I am facing merge conflicts. I want to merge locally and I am using the gitlab manual and tips to do so (see screenshot), but I fail to understand how I can push my locally merged and solved branch back to Gitlab "into" the merge request so that I can finish it.

Gitlab tells me I can solve these conflicts locally:

[image]

So I clicked on ["check out with merge request id"](https://git.domain.next-kraftwerke.de/help/user/project/merge_requests/reviews/index.md#checkout-merge-requests-locally-through-the-head-ref) and followed the tip of adding following to my git config:
`[alias] mr = !sh -c 'git fetch $1 merge-requests/$2/head:mr-$1-$2 && git checkout mr-$1-$2' -` 
... and checking out the branch by using the merge request ID. After doing git mr origin 11, my IDE checks out to a branch called "mr-origin-11".

So far so good! But after merging and solving the conflicts, how do I update my Gitlab merge request? Step 4 in the screenshot tells me to push the branch, but I don't see any changes in Gitlab. Also the branch is called now "mr-origin-11" instead of "email_task" (which is the problem?). So I am confused, why gitlab suggests checking out with the merge request ID if I can't push my solved branch to gitlab anymore. Or Am I doing something wrong?